# How to restrict access to my firefox addon published on addons.mozilla.org

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, mozilla

I developed an addon for firefox which I want to distribute among my group. I don't want to make it visible to everyone. How can I put that restriction for my published addon.

I did the same for chrome extension where my listed emails can install my chrome extension only.

Answer (score 1):

Such an option is not available for extensions **listed** on AMO. It's either available for everyone or not at all.

Unlike CWS, with Firefox you can opt to **self-distribute** the extension (AMO will only do the signing, hosting and updating is on you), and then how you control access is up to you.

However, once someone has the XPI file, they can share it with anyone. This is technically true of Chrome extensions as well: once installed, they can be ripped and shared.

If you truly need to limit functionality for non-members, the only way is to offload some non-trivial part of the program to a server that requires access credentials.